# Retrieve username inside a trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In our database we have a `login` table featuring coloumns `username` and `password`. How can this username be retrieved inside a trigger function so that it can also be audited. `user` keyword inside the  trigger function retrieves the postgresql username, what I need is the application username. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom GUC up in `postgresql.conf`. Use it to store the application username at login using `SET myapp_username`. Access that in triggers with `current_setting(myapp_username)`

Alternately, create a `TEMPORARY` table at user login and `INSERT` the user's application username into it at login. `SELECT` it in triggers where required.

Both of these require that the user cannot run custom SQL directly, of course, but that's generally a requirement of application-level authentication like you're using anyway.

More detail in [Passing user id to PostgreSQL triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13172524/398670)

Comment: @shalin I wrote a more detailed reply to this in another question, in case you're interested. It contains demo code, docs links, and more explanation. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13172524/398670